# How do I get the image from the soap xml

Tags: android, xml, soap

> ```
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>    <soap:Header>
>       <ns3:ComMsgHeader xmlns:ns3="http://apache.org/headers" xmlns:ns2="http://openapi.foodsafety.go.kr">
>          <RequestMsgID/>
>          <ResponseTime>2013-07-12 18:32:45.3245</ResponseTime>
>          <ResponseMsgID/>
>          <SuccessYN>Y</SuccessYN>
>          <ReturnCode>00</ReturnCode>
>          <ErrMsg>NORMAL SERVICE.</ErrMsg>
>       </ns3:ComMsgHeader>
>    </soap:Header>
>    <soap:Body>
>       <ns2:getRecipeItemResponse xmlns:ns2="http://openapi.foodsafety.go.kr">
>          <RecipeItemResponse>
>             <Recipe_name>콩나물밥</Recipe_name>
>             <Image>/UserFiles/searching/recipe/000600.jpg</Image>
>             <Quantity>4</Quantity>
>             <Cook_time>40</Cook_time>
>             <Calorie>401</Calorie>
>             <Level>초보환영</Level>
>             <Master_ingr>쌀 2컵, 콩나물 300g, 쇠고기 100g</Master_ingr>
>             <Cook1_desc>쌀은 미리 씻어 불려놓고 콩나물은 씻어 소금물에 살짝 데쳐 놓는다.</Cook1_desc>
>             <Cook2_desc>쇠고기는 곱게 다져 파, 마늘, 진간장으로 양념하여 볶는다.</Cook2_desc>
>             <Cook3_desc>콩나물 삶은 물을 냄비에 붓고 쌀을 앉혀 밥을 짓다가 끓으면 삶은 콩나물과 쇠고기를 얹어 뜸들인다</Cook3_desc>
>             <Cook4_desc>뜸이 들면 고루 섞어 그릇에 담고 양념장과 함께 낸다.</Cook4_desc>
>          </RecipeItemResponse>
>       </ns2:getRecipeItemResponse>
>    </soap:Body>**strong text**
> </soap:Envelope>
> ```

this is sample xml
How do I get the image from the soap xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the Xml file and get the link to the image. Then use this link to make an http request to the server, this time to download the image itself.